# Is it possible to write complex sentence without subordinate (or dependent) clause?

Tags: grammar, sentences, writing

My first language is NOT english. Currently I am preparing for IELTS exam at the moment. Today I saw a youtube video about IELTS writing task. In this video, the teacher gave an example of **complex sentence** which is:---

> "The amount of people from an English town deciding to start a
>   vegetarian diet increased steadily by approximately 125 from about 75
>   to 200 between 2004 and 2007. "

In another video, the teacher gave some more examples of complex sentences:-

> Between 2004 and 2007, the number of people increased steadily from
>   about 75 to 200.
>
> There was a steady increase in the number of people from about 75 to
>   200 between 2004 and 2007.
>
> The number of people becoming vegetarian experienced a steady increase
>   from about 75 to 200 between 2004 and 2007.

I myself **cannot** see any subordinate clause or dependent clause in the **four** sentences. I do Not know why are they considered as **Complex sentences**. Can anyone help me asap please? My IELTS exam is very near :(.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anybody who teaches people to write "The amount of people" should have their licenses suspended.

Comment: SE frowns on cross-posting on multiple SE sites; since you have received an answer on ELL, the question will probably be deleted here.

Comment: As pointed out by StoneyB, the question is already answered at [ELU](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99643/is-it-possible-to-write-a-complex-sentence-without-a-dependent-clause-and-withou) and thus a duplicate (wasn't able to choose a non-Ling.SE site in the duplicate option for the close vote though, so I just selected "off-topic", althouth I think the question would be okay here).

Comment: Just a helpful tip. It doesn't matter in your IELTS exam whether you think that a sentence is a complex sentence or not. You have far more important things to think about! Good luck!